# Ejb-QL DISTINCT ON

Tags: jpa, ejb, distinct

Is it possible to use PostgreSQL-like DISTINCT ON in EJB-QL query?

What i need to do is to fetch from db records that are distinct on 3 of 10 columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you post your entities?

Imagine there is a `Customer` who has multiple `Reservation`s. This query will return duplicates if the `Customer` has more than one `Reservation`:

```
SELECT c FROM Reservation r, IN(r.customer) c
```

Using the `DISTINCT` keyword ensures that each customer is represented once in the results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Reservation r, IN(r.customer) c
```

I hope this helps.